# Java - Creating high level interface for legacy console program

Tags: java, interface, runtime, exec

I am writing a java application that is suppose to create a interface for a old console program.

I have been trying to use Runtime.exec to run my console program but i am running into issues because Runtime.exec only executes commands and does not hold the console program running.

Is there any way that I can keep the console program running without having to keep the state in the interface to run the program over and over and navigate through the console program every time the user enters an input.

This is the code that i am trying to run. The first exec works properly but then why i try to make the program load it gives me an error that it cannot run the program "load"

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "progam_in_PATH", "-Arg"};

Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
print(getOutput(in,1000));

p = rt.exec("load path/to/file/to/load.txt");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
print(getOutput(in,1000));
```

So my question is. Is there any way to keep the console program running while my java program is running?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sure. Once the Process is started, you can communicate back and forth with the in/out/error streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "progam_in_PATH", "-Arg"};
```

In above statement, change /C to /k

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/k", "progam_in_PATH", "-Arg"};
```

Here is what/k means ( [excerpt from here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) )

> /k : Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

Comment: I tried changing from /c to /k but the Runtime.exec still fails with the same error. "Cannot Run Progam "load" ".

Comment: I added start before the program_in_PATH in your answer.                                          String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/k", "start progam_in_PATH", "-Arg"};                             That way it worked, thank you